# Biosafety Level 1 (BSL-1) surrogate viruses that show greatest similarity to SARS-CoV-2

Tags: virology, coronavirus

I would like to know if there are any viruses that show high similarity to SARS-CoV-2 (particularly in terms of structure) that are very safe to use (i.e., classified as BSL-1).

For example, an avian coronavirus would be good to use but it is BSL-2. Ideally, I would need BSL-1.

Ideally if there were any corona type viruses that were BSL-1 or those which have distinguishing features with proteins emanating from an outer lipid membrane similar to SARS-CoV-2 .

I am particularly interested in finding a virus with similarity to the protruding S1 spike in SARS-CoV-2 (see image)[image: sars cov 2 image fom Glasgow Life Sciences].

Comment: Can you be more specific about 'structure' and 'similarity'. Do you mean similarity in RNA sequence, protein sequence, function, pathogenicity etc?

Comment: Good question! Thanks for your comment. I mean in terms of its most outer appearance/structure. e.g., anything with a similar protruding protein stricture on its outer membrane.

Comment: I added an image too to illustrate that I am interested mainly in any similar viruses that have similar outer protein structures.

Comment: To be further specific. I'm thinking in terms of how it would interact with a (generic) surface. So any virus that is classified as BSL-1 that is similarly covered in protruding protein and/or would interact with a given surface (be that a window, door or even a host cell) in a similar manner.

Comment: What you're looking for is a suitable surrogate. For H1N1 the surrogate used was MS2 coliphage. I recommend going onto https://viralzone.expasy.org/294 and looking at the coronaviridae family. Then find viruses in this family and go onto the atcc website and see what classification BSL a certain strain of the virus is (be careful not to confuse it with genomic RNA from the virus). Adenoviruses with spike cloned onto them (what astra zeneca is doing) could also be an option, but last I checked this was only BSL2. Maybe Orthomyxoviridae (family of influenza) might have some genetically modified.

Comment: Thanks for this info! Very useful. I am not a biologist by training. Navigating this space effectively is a little difficult to me as much of the terminology is alien to me. I'm suprised a suitable surrogate has not already been identified. In my case, I'm after a safe and suitable surrogate which is representative of the coronaviridae family in general based on its outer protein conformation. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Some specific examples would be awesome if anyone can provide some? even if you are not very sure. it would be a big help. thanks